# Cannot read in string from string class

Tags: c++, string

Just a short question and I will be on my way.  Why am I getting errors when I try to read in string using the string class?  The error I receive is: "no operator ">>" matches these operands/operand types are std::istream >> std::string *"

I am starting to use the  class instead of cStrings.  Unfortunately, I keep getting errors when I try to read in a string using cin.  For example:

```
void ProcessEditMenuItems( int menu_choice, std::string fname[], std::string lname[], 
                    std::string phone[], std::string bday[]     /*char fname[][NAME_LENGTH], char lname[][NAME_LENGTH], char phone[][NAME_LENGTH], 
                       char bday[][NAME_LENGTH]*/ )
{
switch ( menu_choice )
{
    case 1:
        std::cout << "\nEnter new first name: ";
        std::cin >> fname;
    break;
    case 2:
        std::cout << "\nEnter new last name: ";
        std::cin >> lname;
    break;
    case 3:
        std::cout << "\nEnter new phone number: ";
        std::cin >> phone;
    break;
    case 4:
        std::cout << "\nEnter new birthday: ";
        std::cin >> bday;
    break;
}
}
```

The above code works for normal cStrings, but when I change the function declaration and definition to the string class it does not work.

Comment: i think you need to learn more. string is _something like_ a char array. so `string fname` would be _something_ like a `char fname[19]`. so no need of `[]` for using string in your case. use `string fname[]` when you need an array of strings!!! :)

Comment: I do need an array of strings.  Hence why I was using string fname [].  If you look at the commented out code, you will see I am trying to replace char fname[][NAME_LENGTH] -- a two dimensional array.

Comment: oh, then `cin >> fname[i]` will put the input to the 'i'th place of the fname array. You cannot do `cin >> fname` because fname is not a string but an array of strings. (operator `>>` of `std::cin` doesn't know what to do when the Right Hand Side of the `>>` operator is an array of strings!! so it should give compilation error.)
Still you need to work on how you pass the parameters. i suggest passing them in as pointers or references.

Comment: @Deamonpog Thank you very much for the reply.  So I change my function header to include "std::string& fname[]", correct?

Comment: yes and its called the **signature** of the function.

Answer (score 3):

Your arguments `fname`, `lname`, `phone`, and `bday` are declared as `std::string arg[]` which for an argument is transformed to `std::string* arg`. That is, they are pointers to `std::string`. You would only have an argument declared with `std::string arg[]` if you want to pass an array of `std::string`s.

If you're passing in a single `std::string` for each argument, then what you actually want is a reference type. For example, `fname` should be `std::string& fname`. The reference allows a `std::string` to be passed into the function without copying, so that when you read into it with `>>` you modify the original object.

Answer (score 2):

You are actually passing arrays of strings, but should pass non-const references to strings.

Change your function prototype to:

```
void ProcessEditMenuItems(
  int menu_choice,
  std::string& fname,
  std::string& lname,
  std::string& phone,
  std::string& bday
)
```

And it should be fine.

When converting from C-strings to `std::strings`, you may use the following conversion table:

```
Old parameter | New parameter      | Description
const char*   | const std::string& | Non-modifiable parameter
char*         | std::string&       | Modifiable string
```

The nicest thing being that you don't need to care about the string size when changing it while you would have to do with a `char*`. Nor do you have to handle deletion/reallocation if a size-increase was needed.

Answer (score 1):

`fname` is an array of `std::string`.  Is the use of arrays a hangover from your earlier use of C strings - `char fname[]`?  If so, you could change to passing `std::string&` instead

```
void ProcessEditMenuItems(int menu_choice,
                          std::string& fname,
                          std::string& lname,
                          std::string& phone,
                          std::string& bday)
```

Comment: If you look at the commented out code, the original cString was a two dimensional array (i.e. char fname[MAX_FRIENDS][NAME_LENGTH]).  Does std::string& fname still work for this?

Comment: Ah, no, it won't work.  If you want to have an array of strings, you'd have decide which index to use then stream into `fname[index]`.  Or you could pass `std::vector<std::string>&` and `push_back` a new string to it if you want to add to the end of a variable array.  (I'll change my answer if you confirm whether either option suits your needs.)

Answer (score 0):

This error is similar to `int arr[2]; arr = 1;`
fname is an array which contains string objects. "std::cin >>" mean extract strings from the standard input. We can only assign string object to fname[0], fname[1] ....
try `std::cin >> fname[0]` instead;